# Redux.js - It is possible to create manually a function listening an another function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, redux, listener

Hi all I'm working on async programming in Redux currently.

I seek for information to create refined Redux Actions, it is all about side effect in Redux and this kind of topics.

I  have seen a snippet in [this article](https://goshakkk.name/redux-side-effect-approaches/) which propose to create listener in order to refined the code.

Here the snippet :

```
// Redux Action
function fetchUser(id) {
  return { type: 'FETCH_USER' };
}

// in some other place, a function listening the Redux Action
// (pseudo-code)
when('FETCH_USER').do((dispatch) => {
  fetch('...').then(user => {
    dispatch({ type: 'FETCHED_USER' });
  }, error => {
    dispatch({ type: 'ERRORED_USER' });
  });
})
```

great but how create manually a function listener in Javascript ? I can't figure out how to do that without writing some callback,

Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

Custom Event Listner in JS:

```js
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", displayDate);

function displayDate() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

The addEventListener() method attaches an event handler to the specified element.

The addEventListener() method attaches an event handler to an element without overwriting existing event handlers.

You can add many event handlers to one element.

You can add many event handlers of the same type to one element, i.e two "click" events.

You can add event listeners to any DOM object not only HTML elements. i.e the window object.

The addEventListener() method makes it easier to control how the event reacts to bubbling.

When using the addEventListener() method, the JavaScript is separated from the HTML markup, for better readability and allows you to add event listeners even when you do not control the HTML markup.

You can easily remove an event listener by using the removeEventListener() method.

Refrence: http://www.kaizou.org/2010/03/generating-custom-javascript-events/

Comment: thanks Dinesh, I would mean I try to create a function listening an another function and not directly the user interaction

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the `event-emitter` module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/event-emitter

Though since you are interested in VanillaJS implementations, here's an example of what an event emitter looks like:

```
var Emitter = {
    _callbacks: {},
    on: function(type, callback) {
        if (!this._callbacks[type]) {
            this._callbacks[type] = [];
        }

        this._callbacks[type].push(callback);
    },
    emit: function (type /* arguments */) {
        if (!this._callbacks[type]) {
            // No event listeners of this type
            return;
        }
        // This creates an array with the remaining arguments after the first
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        this._callbacks[type].forEach(callback => {
            // This runs the callbacks with the args provided to the funciton other than type
            callback.apply(null, args);
        });
    }
}
```

Note that this works anywhere JS works and does not require the DOM to run.

You could easily write this as an ES6 class which would allow you to make many emitters.

There's also a bit of syntax in here that can be simplified greatly in ES6 but I wrote it in old skool javascript for compatibility

---

Edit: I noticed in your comments that you'd like to listen to a function.

The easiest way to do that is to use a Higher Order Function that wraps it and adds an emitter like so:

```
var emittingFunction = function(toEmit, func) {
    return function (/* arguments */) {
        // run the function
        var result = func.apply(null, arguments)
        // Emit the event after the function runs
        Emitter.emit(toEmit, result)
        return result;
    }
}

function tester(name) {
    return 'hello ' + name;
}

// Create our new function with the HOF
var watchedTester = emittingFunction('tester.called', tester);

// Now register a listener for our new event
Emitter.on('tester.called', function (result) {
    console.log('Listened to tester', result);
})

tester() // no log - returns hello
watchedTester() // logs 'Listened to tester hello undefined'
watchedTester('world') // logs 'Listened to tester hello world'
```

Comment: @Webman I added details on how to listen to the execution of a function